# Use Scala with limited Java environment

Tags: java, scala, compilation, jvm, whitelist

I'm working on a project where I can use Scala and other JVM languages in a Java execution environment that only whitelists certain classes

Is there a straightforward way to determine whether all Scala code in a file / project also fits within the whitelist bounds, or does there need to be a similar whitelist for Scala (and all other JVM languages like Groovy, Clojure, etc)

For reference:

- [Whitelist class list](https://docs.icon.community/support/advanced-topics/java-smart-contracts/allowed-methods)
- [Execution environment layer](https://github.com/icon-project/goloop/tree/master/javaee) that passes over the project before finishing compiling, enforcing whitelist

Comment: I assume that the Scala uses the same format as Java's Jar file.  Those are just zip files.  Unzip the .jar file and look at all the classes.  That itself is a list of used classes.  Then you'd need to decompile each class.  I believe any class names used by the class will also be in the .class file.  You should be able to assemble a list of used classes.  There's no automated way of doing this that I know of.

Comment: (post scriptum: I guess all that might not qualify as "straightforward.")

Comment: You may write a **Scalafix** that performs the validation, and fail compilation of any used symbol doesn't belong to the white list. Not sure how straightforward it would be.

Comment: Something similar has been done before, see this old attempt called "scalazzi". It contains rules that blacklist some types/symbols etc rather than whitelist, but it might be good enough. https://github.com/scalaz/scalazzi/blob/master/scalafix.conf